# windows kernel debugging

Tags: c, windows, windows-7, kernel

I am adding stubs for windows divide zero interrupt handler. So, every divide zero interrupt comes to my stub and then I route it to actual windows handler. However I am having some issues in implementation. Is there any way to debug windows instruction flow. Print messages in dbgmessage may not be enough as I am may be loading some wrong eip values from hacked idt table. Is there any kgdb equivalent?

Thanks

Comment: try running windows in ollydbg :)

Comment: In between I am on win7 64 bit.

Comment: "However I am having some issues in implementation." == [PatchGuard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_Patch_Protection)?  "Prohibited modifications include... Modifying the interrupt descriptor table"

Comment: @Ben: Noh, I have disabled the patchguard. Issues are due to some mistakes in my code or some cache issues.

Comment: @agent.smith: That's important information which should have been included in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I would think [WinDbg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg) would be what you need.

Comment: It was said, that dbgmessages are not enough

Comment: @Ulterior - WinDbg provides access to the Windows kernel debugger, not just debug messages.